# What's the meaning of "Calendar" in "School of Graduate Studies Calendar"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

I found [this website](https://sgs.calendar.utoronto.ca/graduate-programs-at-a-glance) which lists all the graduate programs in University of Toronto. But I'm pretty confused about the title of the website: "School of Graduate Studies Calendar".

From my point of view, this website doesn't have anything to do with date, thus doesn't match my understanding of a "Calendar". In dictionary, the word "Calendar" also doesn't have the meaning of "a catalog of something". So what does the word "Calendar" mean on this website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not the title of that web page, it is the title of the entire website.  The website lists all the programs at the University of Toronto School of Graduates Studies, the sessional dates, the requirements of each course, the length and limits of each course, with expectations of how much should be completed in each year and so forth.

I suspect that calling this a "calendar" may be partly historic, and somewhat dialectical. This seems to be what Canadian Universities call their published lists of courses, programs and requirements.  I guess that in the days before the internet, the "calendar" listing school dates was extended with additional information about the school and the programs it offered, until now the "calendar" is mostly a list of courses, not a list of dates.

So it is just the name that Candian universities use for this document.